# Blue banner "Your app is using your location" is not showing after exiting my app

Tags: ios, ios8, core-location

My application is using core location in background mode, when app is in background mode and sending GPS coordinates periodically, the blue banner "Your app is using your location" is not showing (like google map app for example).
Any idea of what I could have missed ?

Comment: Are you sure it *is* sending GPS coordinates, have you confirmed this?

Comment: Yes my app sends GPS coordinates correctly

Answer (score 6):

To show blue bar, you should

1: Enable `Background Location Updates` in target Capabilities. Then set `locationManager` `allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates` to YES;

2: Add `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` in `info.plist` file (8.0+ ask for location). Then call `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` method not `requestAlwaysAuthorization` method.

Comment: Thanks for this! I was looking for a way to display it :)

Answer (score 0):

It only shows for applications registered for when in use location updates.