# iOS8: How to display blue bar "is Using Your Location" with "requestAlwaysAuthorization"

Tags: ios, ios8, core-location, cllocationmanager

How does an app register for location services in the background **and  signification change location services**, i.e. using `requestAlwaysAuthorization`, **and** get the Blue Bar to warn the user that they might want to end their activity?

According to Apple documentation using `requestWhenInUseAuthorization`:

> The system displays a location-services indicator in the status bar when your app moves to the background with active location services.

However,

> Apps cannot use any services that automatically relaunch the app, such as region monitoring or the significant location change service.

The limitation on `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` seems severe (cannot be relaunched if killed by the OS).

Can an app call both the Authorization methods?

Is the app supposed to forgo being relaunched by significant location change services, in order to get the Blue Bar to be seen?

Am I missing something obvious here?

(Similar question is [Blue banner "Your app is using your location" is not showing after exiting my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31341043/blue-banner-your-app-is-using-your-location-is-not-showing-after-exiting-my-ap). Other questions seem to want to get rid of the banner.)

Answer (score 0):

The blue bar only show when you enable Background Location Updates and request when-in-use authorization in iOS 8.

```
Blue bar “is Using Your Location” appears shortly after exiting app
```

Sounds like location manager can't stop immediately. So the blue bar will appear until location manager stop completely. Or maybe it's just a bug .